# Handle slash on Mac and Windows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, backslash, slash

In a JavaScript file I have:

```
__dirname.split('/')
```

This code was written on MAC and it works on that environment. However, this script crashes on my Windows because it can't find the directory, so in order to work I have to change it to this:

```
__dirname.split('\\')
```

The problem is that I can't commit it like this because it will crash on his end after this since he is using MAC.

Is there any way I can edit this block of code in order to work on both envs ?

Thanks

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`path.sep`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep):

```
const path = require('path');
...
__dirname.split(path.sep)
```

Comment: @paulalexandru as with all built-in modules, you have to `require()` it first. See edit.

Comment: @paulalexandru in the file in which you use `path`

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned `__dirname`, I assume that you are referring to NodeJS.

In NodeJS, if you want to split a string into an array, you can use `string.split()`.
By importing the `path` module into your node script, you can do this:

```
const path = require('path');

_dirname.split(path.sep);
```

`path.sep` gives you the separator character for whichever platform you're running on.